# Телеграм бот. При нажатии на кнопку выдаётся ответ. Бот должен выводить все кнопки после каждого ответа

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

```
import random
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('00000000000000000000000');
from telebot import types
a = [""]
b = [""]
c = [""]
d = [""]
e = [""]
f = [""]
g = [""]
h = [""]
i = [""]
j = [""]
k = [""]
l = [""]
m = [""]
n = [""]
o = [""]
p = [""]
first = [a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p]
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "/start":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет")
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data= 'anslib')
        keyboard.add(key_0)
        key_0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data= 'anslib')
                bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text= '', reply_markup=keyboard)    
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "anslib":
        msg = random.choice(first) 
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, msg)
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы пустые кнопки с пустым сообщением отправляете, что должно происходить по-Вашему?

Comment: @MyZik, я убрал содержимое. Мне нужно понять, как зациклить ответ-меню-ответ-меню

Answer (score 0):

В `get_text_messages` во время отправки сообщения есть параметр `reply_markup` . Думаю надо сделать также и в `callback_worker`.
Стоит попробовать примерно следующее:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "anslib":

        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_0 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='', callback_data='anslib')
        keyboard.add(key_0)

        msg = random.choice(first) 
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, msg, reply_markup=keyboard)
```